# Are there any established patterns for a grid populating based on an input?

Tags: tables, search, search-results

I'm working on a system of data entry where a user enters their query in an input field, then can interact with the returned items on a grid that autopopulates based on that query, kind of like my simplified example below. Are there any existing applications that have functionality similar to this?

[image: Input-populated grid.]

Comment: Is the only possible interaction to add the item or are there more options?

Comment: You do have the ability to remove added items, but I'm still trying to decide whether to have them in the same list (a la Listonic in mintpandapl's answer), or to house them in a neighboring table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lot of apps using this pattern, for example shopping lists. In your solution I would change the position of [+] button to the left, because in your case eye has to wander from left to right and that kind of jumping is not friendly.

For example [Listonic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.l&hl=en) from Poland did it right, and looks like this:

[image: Listonic]